# How to add units to Highcharts/Highmaps's last legend/coloraxis?

Tags: highcharts, legend, highmaps

I'd like to add units to my legend/coloraxis of my Heatmap. It would work with this piece of code:

```
    colorAxis: 
    {
        stops: [
        [0, '#c4463a'],
        [0.7, '#fffbbc'],
        [1, '#3060cf']
        ],
        labels: 
        {
            formatter: function () 
            {
                return this.value + "km2";
            }
        }
    }
```

but it would put me the "km2" at each of the numbers in the legend/coloraxis. However, it would be not only sufficient, but surely more clean, to just put once, at the end of the last number. The legend would then read:

-4000, -2000, 0, 2000 km2

Is that possible within Highcharts/Highmaps to put unit at last colorAxis lable? Otherwise, I will probably need to put a text item there by specifying the x/y coordinates, no?

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/mn68sofn/1/).

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code :

```
 labels: {
            formatter: function () {
               if(this.isLast)
                return this.value+"Km2";
                else
                     return this.value;
            }
        }
```

Here [is your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/mn68sofn/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great. However, it doesn't look very pretty now, as the last number is closing the gap to the number before. Any way to move that last number further to the right? With something like this: this.x+60; or so? BTW: Would be nice to move the first number more to the left too...

Comment: I'll try to postion it , meanwhile If you are talking about space b/w 2000 and km2 just add space  return this.value+"   Km2";

Comment: No, it's not the space. The legend should look something [like this](http://i.imgur.com/kQqfwjb.png).

Comment: @luftikus143 If you set `tickPositions` and label's `rotation` to `360` and `align` to `'center'`, then the labels will be placed the same as in your image. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rsd93h5f/

Comment: @Kacper Madej: Wow, impressive coding! Thanks for that. Looks great!